# Check if a key exists in request.files

Tags: python, api, flask, request, flask-restful

I would like to iterate over request.files content and check if a key exists ,
however the key value is : "item_i" , so the key could be one or more  : "item_0" , "item_1" "item_2" ...
i would like to create a loop and retrive the keys if the keys startwith item_ save them in a list
and at the end return the list lenght if it'szero returns an erro no key "item_"

code looks like :

```
result = []
            for (int i = 0; i < request.files.count; i++):
                key = Request.Files.GetKey(i)
                if key.startswith("item_"):
                    result.append(key)

            if len(result) == 0:
                return f" No {item_}key exists !", HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
```

PS : i'm using flask , not sure that request.files.count works but the most important is to iterate over all the request.files items
many thanks .

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stop your route code in the debugger and evaluate type(request.files) you'll see it's a [werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.html).

If you want to check if a key is in request.files you can just do:

```
if "item_0" in request.files:
    #do something
```

If you want to get all the keys from request.files you can use `request.files.keys()` and to get the number of items in request.files you can use `len(request.files)`.

To replicate the code in your question you can use this:

```
result = list()
for key in request.files.keys():
    if key.startswith("item_"):
    result.append(key)
```